# React Native and hardware keys

Tags: android, barcode-scanner, react-native

We're building an app for android in react-native.

Basically, everything is built perfectly, but there is some specific. Which is the devise itself - it's Caribe PL-40L barcode scanner, with built-in laser scanner, scan button etc. It has a hardware keys for numbers and scan, which i'm struggling with - tried a bunch of decisions, starting with react-native-keyevent and DeviceEventEmitter and ending with react-native-cordova-plugin with plugin added for this device.

This device has an app supported with it, which reads laser scans perfectly, but, obviously, we can't use it as we also implemented a business logic in our.

Maybe, just maybe, there is somebody, who know for sure how to handle any hardware button event with React Native (except for back button). I, surely, can switch to Cordova, but i don't really like webview concept.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? I am heading over to a similar problem, I really dont want to switch to Cordova just because of this scanner issue.